# Esperar a que Firebase realice una lectura. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

estoy haciendo una aplicación de Android donde en un momento recupero datos de Firebase.

El problema es que cuando llamo a la función que lee los datos de Firebase, y me devuelve un String con un dato que necesito, la lectura acaba más tarde y el String siempre sale null, a pesar de que un tiempo después es capaz de leer el dato.

¿ Qué debo hacer para que espere a que acabe la lectura de Firebase?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

• En la primera función llamo a la siguiente:

```
String rol="";
        try {
            rol=recuperaRol(correo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

• En la función `recuperaRol()`

```
public String recuperaRol(final String correo) throws InterruptedException {
        final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        final String[] rol = {""};

        db.collection("tabla_usuarios").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                                if (document.getData().get("CORREO").equals(correo)){
                                    rol[0] = (String) document.getData().get("ROL");
                                    System.out.println("ROL encontrado" + rol[0]);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        return rol[0];
    }
```

Comment: Por favor cambia la captura de pantalla por el texto del código y si da algún error, pon la traza completa del mismo en la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para ello. Para ver los errores debes activar la pestaña `LogCat` que suele aparecer en la parte inferior de Android Studio.

Comment: yo lo que haria es poner un progressbar mientras recibe la respuesta

Comment: Listo, no se porqué se el public String recuperaRol.. no se ha puesto en gris. Error no me da ninguno en el LogCat. El problema es que cuando llamo a la funcion recupera rol creo que Firebase realiza la lectura de forma asincrona, por tanto, la ejecución del codigo continúa. Esto hace que el rol, me lo devuelva nulo, aunque más tarde en el run si que sale que lo ha cogido correctamente. Lo que intento hacer, sin éxito, es que hasta que no lea todo de Firebase, no se ejecute lo siguiente, es decir, que lo realice de forma sincrona.

Comment: El pedido a firebase trabaja de forma asincronica, por lo que cuando retornas el dato aun no se ha recibido la respuesta de firebase, lo que debes hacer es quitar el return ya que siempre te dara null. Usa una funcion de callback donde recibas el rol como parametro y se ejecute cuando firebase responda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas teniendo es que no estas manejando la asincronicidad.

Todas las llamadas a Firebase son asíncronas, lo que quiere decir que no espera a que termine para ejecutar la siguiente instrucción de código, simplemente llama a Firebase y continua con la ejecución del programa.
En tu caso, esto esta sucediendo después del `addOnCompleteListener`. Firebase ejecuta esa función y luego ejecuta el `return rol[0];`.

Cuando Firebase termina de leer los datos, te avisa mediante el listener anteriormente definido (`addOnCompleteListener`), pero tu función ya volvió, y para el momento en que volvió el valor de `rol[0]` es `null`.

Para que tu código funcione, deberías hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

1. Hacer que `recuperarRol` devuelva `void`, ya que no vas a obtener el resultado de Firebase de inmediato.

   `public void recuperaRol(final String correo) throws InterruptedException`
2. Crear una interface que te funcione de callback para devolver el valor que te devuelve Firebase.

   ```
   public interface RolCallback {
       void rolRecibido(final String rol);
   }
   ```
3. Implementar esa interface para recibir el valor:

   ```
   String rol = "";
    try {
       recuperaRol(correo, new RolCallback() {
           @Override
           void rolRecibido(final String rolNuevo) {
               rol = rolNuevo;
           }
       });
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   ```
   public void recuperaRol(final String correo, RolCallback callback) throws InterruptedException {
       final String TAG = "MainActivity";
   ```

   `db.collection("tabla_usuarios").get()
           .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                           Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                           if (document.getData().get("CORREO").equals(correo)){
                               final Striing rol = (String) document.getData().get("ROL");
                               if (callback != null) {
                                   callback.rolRecibido(rol);
                               }
                               System.out.println("ROL encontrado" + rol[0]);
                           }
                       }
                   } else {
                       Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                   }
               }
           });
   }`

Comment: Realizando esta acción sigue sin esperar a que termine... lo he realizado tal cual .. el codigo no da ningún error y saca la información, pero igual que antes, continua la ejecución del "hilo principal " sin  esperar a que esta acción termine

Comment: el hilo principal se va a seguir ejecutando... si lo que queres lograr es pausar el hilo principal (cosa que no recomiendo), tenes que usar otras tecnicas de multithreading, como mutexes (soportado nativamente por java) o alguna de las clases que ya tenes disponibles como CountDownLatch. Lo que deberías hacer es poner un loading mientras llama a Firebase, y cuando vuelve de Firebase hacer lo que ibas a hacer con el nuevo rol.