# el spinner no me funciona se llena de valores desde la base de datos pero cuando lo selecciono siempre devuelve -1

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

cuando ejecuto el código logro que mi spinner se llene con los datos de firebase pero cuando lo selecciono para sacar el valor seleccionado con un
`.getSelectedItem()`
siempre me devuelve -1 estoy probando con definirle un item selected listener pero tampoco funciona entiendo que no debería de estar null el espiner ya que el id tanto del layout como del spinner son correspondientes

lo otro es que el setOnItemSelectedListener no esta funcionando cuando selecciono un elemento no aparece el log que le tengo puesto en ninguno de los casos

```
profecionaleControlador controlador = new profecionaleControlador();

    List<String> profecionesList = controlador.getprofesion();
    profecionalList = controlador.getProfecionales(null);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.busqueda);
    posi = 0;

    // Spinner
    Spinner_profesiones = findViewById(R.id.Spinner_profesiones);
    //Button
    tbn_buscar = findViewById(R.id.tbn_buscar);
    //ImageView
    iv_user = findViewById(R.id.iv_user);
    //RecyclerView
    rv_profecionales = findViewById(R.id.rv_profecionales);

    //llenar spinner
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,profecionesList);
    Spinner_profesiones.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner_profesiones.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("onItemSelected","se a seleccionado el item n:" +position);
            Spinner_profesiones.setSelection(position);
            posi = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Log.e("onItemSelected","no se a logrado seleccionar");
        }
```

acá el controlador profesional coloque el método especifico pa no llenar todo de código

```
public List<String> getprofesion(){
    //optener la lista de profecionales de la base de datos

    List<String> profeciones = new ArrayList<>();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection(path_profeciones)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String nombre = document.getData().get("nombre").toString();
                            Log.d("getting:", document.getData().get("nombre").toString());
                            profeciones.add(nombre);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(task.getException());
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents:", task.getException());
                    }

                }
            });



    return profeciones;
}
```

Comment: podrias añadir tu clase  profecionaleControlador, creo que tiene que ver con la forma en que estas creando tu objeto controlador, veo que lo inicializas sin datos, puede ser por esto que te regrese el -1 en todas las pociciones

Comment: el problema era de sincronía me di cuenta por que se parecia mucho a: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335682/esperar-a-que-firebase-realice-una-lectura-android-studio para solucionarlo lleve el spiner al método y lo llene de forma asincrónica